# The intersection of maximal subgroups of a group lies in a maximal subgroup of that group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that the intersection of maximal subgroups of a finite group lies in a maximal subgroup of that group.

**My question**: Can someone please verify my proof below? I am afraid that the two statements in blue are contradictory. Is it really the case?

**Proof**: Let $G$ be finite. Suppose $K \leq G$ and $[G:K]$ is prime. Then,
\begin{equation}\label{amend}
    [G:K] = \frac{\left|G\right|}{\left|K\right|} = p
\end{equation}
where $p$ is a prime. Then, $\left|G\right| > \left|K\right|$, implying that $K$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. $\color{blue}{\textrm{Then, $K$ must be contained in some maximal subgroup of $G$}}$ by the hint; denote such a maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $K$ by $V$. Clearly, $K \leq V$.
which implies $K \leq V \leq G$ and
\begin{equation*}
    [G:K] = [G:V] [V:K] = p 
\end{equation*}
Since $p$ is prime, either $[G:V] = 1 \implies \left|G\right| = \left|V\right| \left( \textrm{and } [V:K] = p\right)$ or $\left([G:V] = p \textrm{ and}\right) [V:K] = 1 \implies \left|V\right| = \left|K\right|$.
Thus, either $\left|G\right| = \left|V\right|$ or $\left|V\right| = \left|K\right|$ which shows that $\color{blue}{\textrm{$K$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$}}$. Then, clearly, $M(G) \subseteq K$.

Comment: @DerekHolt If you look at the original version of the question, it is given that $G$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, fine, so why has this assumption been removed? In any case, the statement is false for (infinite) groups that have no maximal subgroups, because in that case the intersection of all maximal subgroups is equal to the whole group.

Comment: @DerekHolt I removed that by mistake but I added it back now

Comment: Please do not delete good questions such as this one after you receive an answer. That makes it seem like you want to hide it.

Comment: @user21820 Quite honestly, I thought that my question was rather trivial, unnecessary, (and frankly a little embarrassing) which is why I had decided to delete it eventually. But, I see what you're saying. My apologies, I did not intend to cause mayhem.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: That's understandable. I think most people won't mind if you delete when there is no answer yet. But yea when people see the deletion 1 min after the answer they might get negative ideas about the motive. So thanks for clarifying your intention, and no harm done! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. However, you're given that $G$ is finite, so you don't need to check that every subgroup and index is finite along the way. Since $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, you do not need to check that it is a subgroup of $V$. Given that $K$ is a subgroup of $V$ and $V$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $K$ is of prime index, you correctly deduced that $V=K$, i.e. $K$ is maximal. This does not contradict the fact that $K$ is contained in a maximal subgroup; it is contained in itself, though not properly, which is fine.